# Point of intersection of a function with exponential functions

Tags: exponential-function

[image: Im practicing for my test on Monday, I don't quite get how to do this question]

Im practicing for my test on Monday, I don't quite get how to do this question

I tried to make everything same base but that didnt work, combining the 3 base was also quite strange

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match many users' quality standards, so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please edit the question. This will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers

Answer (score 1):

$$y_2 - y_1 = 24+3^{x}-3^{x+2} = 24 + 3^x \left(1-3^2\right)$$
Now at the intersection point, $y_2 = y_1$ giving,
$$24 + 3^x \left(1-3^2\right) = 0$$
This should be straightforward. You should always try combining the exponential parts or unknown parts of an equation whenever you see something like this.